# How to pass a table column header as a parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel table with stock market symbols as column headers, e.g. HES, MTDR, OXY, .... The columns contain market data associated with the corresponding header:

Type  HES   MTDR   OXY   ...
Open  62.22 30.56  78.52 ...
Close 62.96 30.52  79.01 ...
...

When I receive a specific stock symbol, e.g. OXY, from

```
Public function getMarketData(colName as String, dataType as Integer) as Double
```

I need to access the desired data in the column headed by that stock symbol, e.g.

```
getMarketData = [tblMarketData[OXY]].Rows(dataType)
```

Q: How do I extract OXY from colName for use  in the above statement? Do I need to use EVALUATE?

```
getMarketData = [tblMarketData[colName]].Rows(dataType)
```

generates the error message 'Object required' because tblMarketData[]  expects the actual column header OXY, not a variable containing OXY.

Comment: Can you show some example data and expected output? And is this parameter being passed in code? Where is your broader code?

Comment: Please [edit] that info into the question.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to access the `ListColumns` object, using the header as a key. You could then read the data contained within that column, using the `DataBodyRange` property. In the example below I've read that range into an array and have passed back the item at index 6.

```
Private Function FetchData(colName As String)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim col As ListColumn
    Dim data As Variant

    Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set col = tbl.ListColumns(colName)
    data = col.DataBodyRange.Value2

    'Obtain 6th item in array.
    FetchData = data(6, 1)

End Function
```

This function could be called like so:

```
    Debug.Print FetchData("OXY")
```

**Edit for follow-up question:**

The extraction of your column name will very much depend on the nature of the full search string. In principle, though, you'd iterate each of your column headers to see if you could find a match of some kind. In the sample below I've put a simple `Like` comparison which would certainly fail if, for example, the text contained "HES" elsewhere. Without being able to see your text strings, it's difficult to be more precise, so you might have to tighten the extraction rules based on the text strings you have.

The function could look like this:

```
Private Function FetchDataItem(txt As String, idx As Long) As Variant
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim col As ListColumn, refCol As ListColumn
    Dim data As Variant

    'Find the appropriate column.
    Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    For Each col In tbl.ListColumns
        If txt Like "*" & col.Name & "*" Then
            Set refCol = col
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'If there's no match then return empty.
    If refCol Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'Retrieve the data item from array.
    data = refCol.DataBodyRange.Value2

    'If index is out of range then return empty.
    If idx < LBound(data, 1) Or idx > UBound(data, 1) Then Exit Function

    FetchDataItem = data(idx, 1)

End Function
```

... and could be called as below (includes a couple of sample strings):

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim arbitraryText As String, failText As String
    Dim col As ListColumn

    arbitraryText = "randomtextwithOXYinit"

    'Read item 6 from column OXY.
    Debug.Print FetchDataItem(arbitraryText, 6)

    'An example of how the extraction could fail - note the 'HES' in the string.
    failText = "I'M A THESBIAN BUT AM LOOKING FOR OXY"
    Debug.Print FetchDataItem(failText, 6)


End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to me that tbl.ListColums (colName) expects colName to be the actual column header, e.g. OXY. But in my case i have a string variable, say colName that is not the column header but contains the column header OXY. So the question remains how to extract OXY from colName to use it in tbl.ListColumns("OXY")?

Comment: I think I follow you, but could you add an example or two of what the string variable and columns headers contain - ideally do this by editing your question so others can see it too - I'll try to amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, Ambie, that will work. I was trying to find a solution using [tblMarketData[colName]], but where colName is the actual column header OXY. Perhaps I need to use EVALUATE to extract OXY from colName?

Comment: I've made an edit, but you may well need to adjust your extraction code depending on the content of your 'search string'.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Ambie. Your edit works, However, because my entire code is based on the TableObject, I'm looking for a TableObject solution if one exists. See my edit of the original question.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, doesn't my first answer do what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, your first  answer works, but it doesn't answer my specific question. Thanks.